# Double Grob-Coca-cola Gambit?

Tags: opening, history, terminology, gambits

I was using the opening explorer on Chess.com when I came upon the following line

1.g4 g5 2. f4 (Coca-cola gambit)!?

How did this opening get its name? It sounds like Coca-cola walked up to Fide and payed some money for some weird advertisement.

Comment: 1. a4 b5 (CitrusCornflakes gambit)

Comment: FIDE has nothing to do with opening names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Sense of Humor

There are several real but somewhat silly openings that gets its name. Sodium Attack (1. **Na**3), Ammonia opening (1, Nh3), Meadow Hay Gambit (1. a4 e5 2. Ra3 Bxa3), Picklepuss Defence (1. e4 h5 2. d4 Nf6).

No one will actually play these in tournaments or something, they serves no useful purpose (except maybe training), but they're funny. Similar to code golf.

Coca-cola is very likely just something that sounds humorous.

Comment: I was going to add Anderssen opening (1. a3) to the silly opening list, but I realized that won't support the second paragraph. It gots its name because it *did* happen.

Comment: @bof Alright then. Maybe 1. a3 a5 2. b4 is a more appropiate example.